# Refer to a Child item using LINQ inline SELECT

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a custom model from a List of Objects and the code i am using is like below

```cs
var dataset = await query.Select(c => new ContactListModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                Email = c.Email,
                EmailAlternative = c.EmailAlternative,
                JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
                CompanyName = (c.Company != null) ? c.Company.Name : "",
                AddressCountry = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.IsPrimary) != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary).Country.Name : "",
                AddressCounty = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary) != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary).CountyText : "",
                AddressPostCode = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary) != null ? c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary).PostCode : ""                    
            }).OrderByDynamic(sortBy, sortDirection).Paginate((tableState.Page * tableState.PageSize), tableState.PageSize).ToListAsync();
```

While assign properties AddressCountry , AddressCounty and AddressPostCode (there are 2,3 more properties like this needs to be assigned from PrimaryAddress instance)
i am referring to the PrimaryAddress item from the list of available address values binded to the object

Is there any way to avoid the repetition of  filtering to PrimaryAddress each time when setting the property

I tried to add one more property PrimaryAddress of type ContactAddress  and then inside the above select statement i assigned the value as

```cs
var dataset = await query.Select(c => new ContactListModel
            {
              -----
              PrimaryAddress = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary),
              AddressCountry = PrimaryAddress.Country.Name,
              AddressCounty = PrimaryAddress.CountyText,
              --
            }).OrderByDynamic(sortBy, sortDirection).Paginate((tableState.Page * tableState.PageSize), tableState.PageSize).ToListAsync();
```

But the error i am getting is the name 'PrimaryAddress'  does not exists in the current context

OrderByDynamic & Paginate is for handling the Sorting and pagination and they are helper extensions I used.

Comment: I think I'd just download the related prop and get the Mapper to pull it out. If you do a double select, does it translate ?

Comment: What do you meant by double select? At present its working perfectly fine based on the first approach , only problem is i am doing a filtering on address each time i assign address related property

Comment: What version of EF (core) are you using ?

Comment: @CaiusJard EF Version 5.0.10 is used in my project

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient way to do this is to switch to query syntax and use `let`:

```cs
var dataset = await (
    from c in query
    let primaryAddress = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary)
    select new ContactListModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        FirstName = c.FirstName,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        Email = c.Email,
        EmailAlternative = c.EmailAlternative,
        JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
        CompanyName = c.Company.Name,
        AddressCountry = primaryAddress.Country.Name,
        AddressCounty = primaryAddress.CountyText,
        AddressPostCode = primaryAddress.PostCode                   
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Note that I removed the null checks. If `query` is an `IQueryable` from Entity Framework (or another O/R mapper) then it will be translated into SQL, which eliminates the need for null checks. If `query` is an in-memory list of objects you can use `c.Company?.Name`, etc.

Also note that you may want to order `Addresses` by some property so you have control over which address is "first".

The same goal can be achieved by using a `from - from` query (or, `SelectMany` under the hood):

```cs
var dataset = await (
    from c in query
    from primaryAddress in c.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsPrimary)
        .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ContactListModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        FirstName = c.FirstName,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        Email = c.Email,
        EmailAlternative = c.EmailAlternative,
        JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
        CompanyName = c.Company.Name,
        AddressCountry = primaryAddress.Country.Name,
        AddressCounty = primaryAddress.CountyText,
        AddressPostCode = primaryAddress.PostCode                   
    }).ToListAsync();
```

The addition `DefaultIfEmpty()` makes the query return contacts without primary addresses, just as in the first query.

If `query` is indeed an `IQueryable` it may be worth while investigating which of both alternatives generates the best SQL in terms of the the database engine's query execution plan. In EF core, the second alternative only generates one subquery to get the primary address, whereas the first one does that for each `primaryAddress` property.

Comment: first one works correctly whereas second one generates random error like he LINQ expression 's' could not be translated.
 Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.  Not sure is it because of some missing or possible null data's.

Comment: That's the problem of (obviously) not being able to your exact code. The best I can do is run *similar* queries in EF core 5 and then the second query is preferred. Maybe this `Paginate` call does something EF doesn't like, hard to tell.

Comment: Although I can add `OrderBy` and `Skip-Take` to it. (By the way, the first query in method (fluent) syntax is compiled to two chained `Select` statements under the hood.)

Comment: In second one you forgot `DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @Svyatoslav You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
              .....
             PrimaryAddress = c.Addresses.Select(x=>
              new PrimaryAddress {
                                  Country = x.Country.Name,
                                  County = x.CountyText
                                  }).FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary),
            CompanyName = (c.Company != null) ? c.Company.Name : ""
            }).ToListAsync();
```

you can leave address as it is, or  you can use AddressCountry, AddressCounty, AddressPostCode,  you can get them through the ContactListModel getters

Answer (score 0):

By double select, I mean:

```
var dataset = await query.Select(c => new { c, PA = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsPrimary) })
.Select(at => new ContactListModel
{
    Id = at.c.Id,
    FirstName = at.c.FirstName,
    LastName = at.c.LastName,
    Email = at.c.Email,
    EmailAlternative = at.c.EmailAlternative,
    JobTitle = at.c.JobTitle,
    CompanyName = at.c.Company,
    AddressCountry = at.PA.Country.Name,
    AddressCounty = at.PA.CountyText,
    AddressPostCode = at.PA.PostCode : ""                    
})
```

It's the method syntax form of what Gert posted in the query syntax (first example)

I'm no fan of the SQL generated (in either this case or Gert's first), something like (not exact but should give the idea):

```
SELECT
  c.Id,
  ...
  (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM Addresses WHERE Id = c.AddressId AND IsPrimary = 1) Name,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Country FROM Addresses WHERE Id = c.AddressId AND IsPrimary = 1) Country,
  (SELECT TOP 1 PostCode FROM Addresses WHERE Id = c.AddressId AND IsPrimary = 1) PostCode
FROM
  Contacts c
```

Hopefully SQLS can optimize that to just a single lookup.. I think I'd prefer a filtered include for a more straightforward JOIN and use a mapping library (or null coalescing) to extract the data C# side. Drop a comment after you add the info as to your EF(C) version so it's clear whether that's an option

Comment: the query 1 is working perfectly fine , but not sure about the performance as this is server side pagination query to deal with thousands of records

Comment: I can't answer the performance concern, only you can; stop short of running anything that enumerates the queryable, and inspect it(the queryable) in the debugger. It has a DebugView from which you can retrieve the built query, and you can run it in SSMS with "Include actual execution plan" turned on so you can see how it will be executed. If you need performance help with the query e.g here, be sure to post the plan as well as th query text (and say EF generates it). As noted, consider a filtered include instead

Comment: Filtered include example: `context.Contacts.Include(c => c.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsPrimary))` .. it's hard to recommend because we can't see where query came from/what it is